# D3 splitting data string to characters

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a D3 selector reference that I am using to populate a selector drop down.  Some of the time, I want to populate the selector with a single value that I am grabbing from another selector.

I can tell via console and debugger that the value of `var b = "201701"` and the type is string.

The problem is that when I try to populate this node using the value b, D3 splits the string to characters and I get a selector with 6 options corresponding to `"2","0","1","7","0","1"`.

Does anyone know how to prevent D3 from splitting the string?

```
    var b = beginningSelector.node().value;
    console.log(typeof b);
    console.log(b);
    endingSelector.selectAll("option")
      .data(b)
      .enter()
      .append("option")
      .attr("value", function (d) { return d; })
      .text(function (d) { return d; });
  });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's the expected behaviour of the `data()` method. In D3, `data()` accepts three things:

1. An array
2. A function
3. Nothing

That being said, here is the cause of the confusion: both strings and arrays in JavaScript have the `length` method, and can be accessed using square brackets. With a string:

```js
var string = "helloworld";
for (i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
  console.log(string[i])
}
```

Now the **exact same code** with an array:

```js
var arr = ["hello", "wolrd"];
for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  console.log(arr[i])
}
```

Do you see? It doesn't break, it doesn't throw an error... but it gives a different result.

Because of that, `data()` will not break with a string... however, it will treat the string as if it was an array:

```js
var foo = d3.select("body").selectAll("foo").data("helloworld").enter();
console.log(foo.data())
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

**Solution**: if you want to treat the string as a single datum, use square brackets:

```
endingSelector.selectAll("option")
    .data([b])
```

Look at the console:

```js
var foo = d3.select("body").selectAll("foo").data(["helloworld"]).enter();
console.log(foo.data())
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```